# Not able to use array-to-tree npm module in angular4

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to use array-to-tree npm module in angular typescript. I tried `import * as arraytotree from 'array-to-tree';` and in constructor `console.log(arraytotree(this.dataOne));`.

But I am getting error in console **ERROR
Error: arraytotree is not a function**

[slack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqdmuy)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
import * as arrayToTree from 'array-to-tree';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  dataOne = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Portfolio',
      parent_id: undefined
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Web Development',
      parent_id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Recent Works',
      parent_id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'About Me',
      parent_id: undefined
    }
  ];

  data = arrayToTree(this.dataOne);

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.data );
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"array-to-tree": "^3.3.0"
```

**Note:** If you don't assign result of arrayToTree(this.dataOne) to a variable then typescript will throw error

```
[ts] Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
(method) AppComponent.arrayToTree(this: any, dataOne: any): any
```